# Django Bootstrap + Angular?

Tags: django, angular

I am creating a website with the latest version of Django and Bootstrap 4 with REST. I was wondering if I should use a frontend JS framework like Angular or react but I am not sure if that is the best approach. should I integrate Angular into the site or  should i just rely on more traditional frameworks like jquery?

The site will be mobile friendly and I will be adding more content and functionallity over time.

Im not asking how to do it. just if its the right direction to go.

Comment: The major modern frameworks (Angular, React, Vue) are all great ways to go for mobile-friendly, reactive web applications. You can also just use vanilla JS depending on how big and detailed your app is going to be. Wouldn't really recommend jQuery as it was created to address missing features in the JS-DOM API, but JS has been updated a lot and pretty much everything jQuery lets you do is available in vanilla JS (without importing a large library).

Answer (score 0):

They all have pros and cons, so there isn't a single correct answer.

JQuery is old and gets used less and less, I wouldn't really suggest it, unless you're trying to create something very simple (although bootstrap uses it).

React or Angular? Probably the biggest difference is that in Angular you have controllers separated from the html, while in React you create reusable components and the logics is mixed with the html (or part of it). They're both good frameworks, I personally prefer React but it's just a matter of preference. Regarding the use with Django, I think you'll find enough resources for both. Regarding current popularity, React is a little favourite at the moment.

If you want to get a glimpse of both before deciding, there are some good free interactive courses on freeCodeCamp.org (not sure if they're free on Codecademy)